# CSS hover stops animation

Tags: css

I've got a `<span>` with some text in it and when you hover over it an image comes sliding down the page. So far so good. However, when your mouse accidentally hovers over the image, the animation will be stopped. I do not want that.

```css
.coffee {
    -webkit-transition: color 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: color 0.2s linear;
    -o-transition: color 0.2s linear;
    -ms-transition: color 0.2s linear;
    transition: color 0.2s linear;
    z-index: 10;
}
.coffee:hover {
    color: #B88A00;
}
.coffee img {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 280px;
    top: 50px;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: top 0.4s ease-in-out, opacity 0.6s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: top 0.4s ease-in-out, opacity 0.6s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: top 0.4s ease-in-out, opacity 0.6s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: top 0.4s ease-in-out, opacity 0.6s ease-in-out;
    transition: top 0.4s ease-in-out, opacity 0.6s ease-in-out;
}
.coffee:hover img {
    top: 150px;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: can you create an example in http://jsfiddle.net for better understanding

Comment: And I have created my first jsfiddle example; 
http://jsfiddle.net/quLKb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per i understand may be that's you want. Write like this:

**HTML**

```
<span class="coffee"><u>coffee</u></span>!
<img src="image.jpg" alt="Coffee!"/>
```

**CSS**

```
.coffee:hover + img{
    top: 150px;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/quLKb/2/

Comment: Some explanation as to how this works: previously, the `img` was inside the `.coffee` which means that any mouse event bubbles from the `img` to its parent(s). When you hover the `img` after hovering `.coffee`, the `.coffee:hover img` selector gets re-triggered which causes the `img` to jump down again. By moving the `img` outside `.coffee`, the `img` events no longer reach `.coffee` and the `:hover` selector doesn't get triggered again.

Comment: As per OP question he didn't want image to stopped when he accidentally hovers over the image. But image is inside   **.coffee** span which trigger when OP hover over image. So, for this it's good if we move the image outside **.coffee** span. Then the image is not stopped when you hover over image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pointer-events attribute. If you set it to none, mouse events are omitted on elements with that css-rule applied.

```
.coffee img {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Here's the modified example: http://jsfiddle.net/kFd9g/